# Array.map and Typescript Object spread operator not mapping to original array

Tags: typescript

I have an array of members in Typescript.

```
const members = [
  {
    name: 'John Lennon',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Led Zeppelin',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Freddie Mercury',
    id: 3
  }
];
```

When I try to map over it and add key

```
members.map(member => {
    member.designation = 'Singer';
    return member;
 });
```

It successfully overwrites an array and add key designation. But when I try doing the same thing using Object spread operator.

```
members.map(member => ({
  ...member,
  designation: 'Singer'
}));
```

It successfully compiles with no error, but at the same time does not map the key `designation` over my members array.

Is it the correct way to do, or am I missing something and it is just a problem with Typescript Object spread operation.

Comment: why do you have to use parentheses in the 2nd map call? I mean : member => ({... and not member => {...?  I tried without parentheses and I got an error but I don't understand why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example you modify the object, in the second one you create a new object, that will have the values of the original member and the new designation property. You need to take the new object array created by `map` and use that:

```
var memberWithDesignation = members.map(member => ({
  ...member,
  designation: 'Singer'
}));
console.log(memberWithDesignation[0].designation); // Will output Singer
```